# Throw FaultExceptions in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I have the following class implementing my service

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class CatalogueService : ICatalogueService
```

And In a method I'm throwing a `FaultException`:

```
public List<ProductType> GetProductType()
{
    bool isThrow = true; 
    if (isThrow)
        throw new FaultException(new FaultReason(new FaultReasonText("My fault Reason!")), new FaultCode("my fault code here"));
    else
    {
        .......
    }
}
```

On Silverlight code behind file I am trying to show the `FaultException` Message in the `Async Completed` event:

```
void service_GetProductTypeCompleted(object sender, GetProductTypeCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        pType = e.Result.ToList();
        cboProductType.DataContext = pType;
    }
    else
    {
        FaultException fault = e.Error as FaultException;
        MessageBox.Show(fault.Reason.ToString());
    }
}
```

But the problem is instead of throwing `FaultException` its throwing `CommunicationException`. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Also on `MessageBox.Show(fault.Reason.ToString());` I get `NullReferenceException`

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I guess it is failing even before your code execution.....are you able to hit brakpoint in service?

Comment: Code advice: `fault` may be a null - change to this `MessageBox.Show(fault ==null?"":fault.Reason.ToString());`

Comment: @Viru In the `service.svn.cs` it does throw this exception and then goes to `Reference.cs` where it thows `CommunicationException - Not Found`